# Google play services keeps crashing

Tags: samsung, google-play-services

Google play services keeps crashing every 3 to 10 seconds, and everything google related on my tablet won't load. It started this morning when i powered on my tablet. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy TabA 8.0 with Android version 7.1.1. What can I do to be able to use my tablet again?